# How to extract text from a notes column in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, reporting-services

I want to extract some text which is in a `Notes` column in Table X and display it as column fields in a SSRS report.

Ex: Notes Column

```
7/7/2014 4:38:03 PM  Timothy Hebbar
New incident created in the ARI DT Ext queue

7/7/2014 4:38:12 PM  Timothy Hebbar
Owner changed from 'Timothy Hebbard' to '<empty>'
Status changed from 'Owned' to 'New'

7/8/2014 8:22:51 AM  Stewart Rose
Owned Tier I

7/8/2014 8:24:26 AM  Stewart Rose
Owner changed from '<empty>' to 'Stewart Rose'
Status changed from 'New' to 'Owned'

7/10/2014 7:04:27 AM  Stewart Rose
Queue changed from 'ARI DT Ext' to 'AIG DT'

7/10/2014 7:19:13 AM  Stewart Rose
Status changed from 'Owned' to 'Closed'
```

How to extract 'Timothy Hebbar' as Name1, 'Stewart Rose' as Name2, 'ARI DT Ext' as Queue1, and 'AIG DT' as Queue2 from the above Notes column. Please help me with a SQL/TSQL logic to extract the same. Should I use the `Like` operator to search the text and `charindex` / `patindex` to achieve this, if so how?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840138/sql-query-to-extract-text-from-a-column-and-store-it-to-a-different-column-in-th already answered

Comment: not quite the same problem that was one item per record, in a fixed location. This is many-to-one (many note parts to one source record)

Comment: You indicate a pivot through [name1] and [name2] but what if there are more names? What about the dates, are these ignored? Are the dates always in MM/DD/YYYY h:m:s AM/PM sequence? How large is the item of text following each name? Does the note contain carriage return/linefeed pairs? or other non-printing characters?

Comment: Yes your are correct its many note parts to one source record. "Owner changed from 'Name1' to 'Name2' and Queue changed from 'Queue1' to 'Queue2' is common in all the notes. Date is always MM/DD/YYYY h:m:s AM/PM sequence. All the above text appears in one row in SQL without any carriage return, but there is space before date sequence.